# Create Neo4j database using CSV files

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have 2 `CSV` files which I want to convert into a `Neo4j` database. They look like this:

first file:

```
name,enzyme
Aminomonas paucivorans,M1.Apa12260I
Aminomonas paucivorans,M2.Apa12260I
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,M1.BceNI
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,M2.BceNI

second file 

name,motif
Aminomonas paucivorans,GGAGNNNNNGGC
Aminomonas paucivorans,GGAGNNNNNGGC
Bacillus cellulosilyticus,CCCNNNNNCTC
```

As you can see the common factor is the `Name` of the organism and the. Each `Organism` will have a few `Enzymes` and each `Enzyme` will have 1  `Motif`. `Motifs` can be same between enzymes . I used the following statement to create my database:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file1.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(e:Enzyme { name: csvLine.enzyme})
CREATE (o)-[:has_enzyme]->(e) //or maybe CREATE UNIQUE?

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file2.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(m:Motif { name: csvLine.motif})
CREATE (o)-[:has_motif]->(m) //or maybe CREATE UNIQUE?
```

This gives me errors on the very first line at `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` which says `Invalid input 'S': expected`. If I get rid of ti, the next error I get is `WITH is required between CREATE and LOAD CSV (line 6, column 1)
"MATCH (o:Organism { name: csvLine.name}),(m:Motif { name: csvLine.motif})"` . I googled this issue which led me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755289/cypher-query-load-csv-not-responding-in-neo4j-2-1) . I tried the answer given ther (refreshing the browser cache) but the problem persists. WHat am I doing wrong here? Is the query correct? Is there an another solution to this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using ?

Comment: I am using the `2.1.3` version

Answer (score 2):

Your queries have two issues at once:

1. You can't refer to a local file just with "file1.csv", because neo4j is expecting a URL
2. You're using `MATCH` in cases where the data may not originally exist; you need to use `MERGE` there instead, which basically acts like the create unique comment you added.

I don't know what the source of your specific error message is, but as written it doesn't look like these queries could possibly work.  Here are your queries reformulated, so that they will work (I tested it on my machine with your CSV samples)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/myuser/tmp/file1.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (o:Organism { name: coalesce(csvLine.name, "No Name")})
MERGE (e:Enzyme { name: csvLine.enzyme})
MERGE (o)-[:has_enzyme]->(e);
```

Notice here 3 merge statements (`MERGE` basically does `MATCH` + `CREATE` if it doesn't already exist), and the fact that I've used a `file:` URL.

The second query gets formulated basically the same way:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/myuser/tmp/file2.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (o:Organism { name:  coalesce(csvLine.name, "No Name")})
MERGE (m:Motif { name: csvLine.motif})
MERGE (o)-[:has_motif]->(m);
```

**EDIT** I added `coalesce` in the Organism's `name` property.  If you have null values for `name` in the CSV, then the query would otherwise fail.  Coalesce guarantees that if `csvLine.name` is null, then you'll get back "No Name" instead.

Comment: The `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` still shows and error. I got rid of it to see if the query works but it shows the error `Cannot merge node using null property value for name`

Comment: Ah, so that error message means that one of the "name" values in your CSV is null.  Will update the answer in a sec....

Comment: I googled the issue and it seems that creation of mass nodes usually gives this error. I added the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` and re ran the query, now the error is little more detailed : `Cannot merge node using null property value for name (Failure when processing URL 'file:/Users/GAMER/Documents/Neo4j/csvs/name_enzyme.csv' on line 2. No rows seem to have been committed. Note that this information might not be accurate.)`

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand what it expects as a file path. Does it ONLY expect URL's? I used the exact same format as you gave in the answer but it says `cannot load resource`. My path looks like this `file:Users/GAMER/Desktop/cypher/name_enzyme.csv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62133/discussion-between-beginner-and-frobberofbits).