# Cypher code for loading relationships into neo4j ignoring data in csv column

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm loading relationships into neo4j. This worked fine for me:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "<link to topic relationships.csv>" AS csvLine MATCH (work:Work {id: csvLine.recordIdentifier}),(topic:Subject {topic: csvLine.topicID}) CREATE work-[:ISABOUT]->topic;
```

But this very similar scenario is not working for me:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "<link to AuthorRel.csv on GitHub>" AS csvLine MATCH (c:Creator { name: csvLine.creatorID}), (w:WORK { id: csvLine.recordIdentifier}) CREATE c-[:CREATED]->w;
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
493 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

This part works,

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeardLibrary/graphs-without-ontologies/master/GraphData/AuthorRel.csv" AS csvLine return csvLine;
```

and this works

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeardLibrary/graphs-without-ontologies/master/GraphData/AuthorRel.csv" AS csvLine MATCH (w:Work { id: csvLine.recordIdentifier}) return w;
```

but it breaks down when I try to MATCH on :Creator name:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeardLibrary/graphs-without-ontologies/master/GraphData/AuthorRel.csv" AS csvLine MATCH (c:Creator { name: csvLine.creatorID}) return c;
```

I got an error message about NULL values, so I tried this (from [Create Neo4j database using CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090984/create-neo4j-database-using-csv-files)):

```
  neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeardLibrary/graphs-without-ontologies/master/GraphData/AuthorRel.csv" AS csvLine MATCH (w:WORK { name: csvLine.recordIdentifier}) MERGE (c:Creator { name:  coalesce(csvLine.creatorID, "No Name")}) CREATE (c)-[:Created]->(w);
    +-------------------+
    | No data returned. |
    +-------------------+
    Nodes created: 1
    Relationships created: 52
    Properties set: 1
    Labels added: 1
    998 ms

    neo4j-sh (?)$ match (c)-[r:Created]->(w) return c,r,w limit 10;

    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26273]{} | Node[278029]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2031670"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26272]{} | Node[278030]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2019322"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26275]{} | Node[278031]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2031713"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26274]{} | Node[278031]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2031713"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26277]{} | Node[278031]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2031713"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26276]{} | Node[278031]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2031713"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26279]{} | Node[278032]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2026618"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26278]{} | Node[278033]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2027194"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26281]{} | Node[278033]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2027194"} |
    | Node[278478]{name:"No Name"} | :Created[26280]{} | Node[278034]{name:"oai:dash.harvard.edu:1/2027199"} |
```

The name data is not being picked up from the CSV. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo in the scenario that "is not working" for you. The `WORK` node's property name should be `name`, not `id`.